# EF Core migration seems to ignore context option

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration, dbcontext, asp.net-core-identity

Whilst adding Identity to my project I am doing so via a second context.

However, when running the following command

```
dotnet ef migrations add IdentityInitial -p .\DOH.Data -s .\DOH.API 
          -c AppIdentityDbContext -o DOH.Data\Identity\Migrations --verbose
```

I get the following output

```
Using assembly 'DOH.Data'.
Using startup assembly 'DOH.API'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\vic\Documents\projects\BugTracker\DOH\DOH.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\vic\Documents\projects\BugTracker\DOH\DOH.API'.
Using root namespace 'DOH.Data'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\vic\Documents\projects\BugTracker\DOH\DOH.Data\'.
Remaining arguments: .
The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.1' is older than that of the runtime '5.0.5'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'DOH.API'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Found DbContext 'ApplicationContext'.
Found DbContext 'AppIdentityDbContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'AppIdentityDbContext'.
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'PersonApplicationRole' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

The entity `PersonApplicationRole` is an existing entity that is referenced in the `ApplicationContext`.

This entity has already been set up in the database via a previous migration using a composite key, so I know that part works

If I change the entity definition to cope with the error just to get through the Identity migration, I end up with a migration that has all of the original entities referenced from `ApplicationContext` as well as the tables that need would be created as part of the Identity set up.

So this feels like the `-c` option is being ignored.

This is the definition of `ApplicationContext`:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext>
{
    public ApplicationContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(@Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/../DOH.API/appsettings.Development.json").Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("doh.dev");
        builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        return new ApplicationContext(builder.Options);
    }
}

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
}
```

This is the current `AppIdentityDbContext`:

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

These are the two connection strings

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "doh.dev": "Host=x.x.x.x;Port=5432;Username=dohdbsvc;Password=******;Database=dohdb;",
    "doh.dev.identity": "Host=x.x.x.x;Port=5432;Username=dohdbsvc;Password=******;Database=doh.identitydb;"
  },
```

And here are the two contexts as included in my startup

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors();
            options.UseNpgsql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("doh.dev"));
        });

services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors();
            options.UseNpgsql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("doh.dev.identity"));
        });
```

For reference, this is a .net core 3.1 project using the following packages

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.5
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 5.0.2
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 5.0.5
```

I have been through the docs and countless examples others have posted on various blogs and forums and I appear to be following recommended practice, so if anyone can see why this is happening, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Have you tried to run this: `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I believe in my case it was down to version mismatches in the EF packages vs the version of .net core I was using at the time which was 3.1. I've since been able to complete the exact same thing on a .net 5 project with versions in sync and not faced the same issue.